# Seeing "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ABC" in Visual Studio Code Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, package

This is my current project folder settings in VSCode:

```
main_folder
    -folder1

        __init__.py
        main.py

        -core
            __init__.py
            core.py

        -checker
            __init__.py
            checker.py

    -venv
```

The problem arises when I try to import a class from **init**.py in core_folder by doing this:

`from core import MyClass`

Funny thing here is that when I right click on VSCode and select `Run Python File in Terminal`, `IT WORKS!`

But when I select all the lines in my main.py and run `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named core.`

My understanding is that since `folder1` has `__init__.py`, and a file from that folder is being executed, all the subfolders with `__init__.py` will be recognized as modules and I should be able to import from `core`. This works when running this file in the terminal but why not in the `Selection/Line in Python Terminal`?

Comment: "Run Python File in Terminal" is to run the current python file in the python terminal, and "Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal" is to run the python code in the python interactive window one by one.  It is recommended that you use the green button at the top right of VS Code to run the python file.

Comment: @JillCheng Thanks for the helpful response and sorry for not getting back earlier.